# Does more cores (-j option) than available make SCons builds slower?

Tags: python, build, multiprocessing, scons

I have 2 cores in my CPU. Will build get slower with SCons if I specify `--jobs=4`? The reason why I am asking is because Python 2 [runs slower on multiple cores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31386382/why-does-this-python-script-run-4x-slower-on-multiple-cores-than-on-a-single-cor).

Actually I am thinking about adding something `--jobs=4` to all my projects as default.

In case the answer is platform-dependent, the compiler is GCC, the platform is Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking building with scons -j # will be faster than building serially.

The link you posted applies to running pure python code.  However since most of the time spent in a SCons build is waiting for external tools to complete (compile, link,etc) that benchmark doesn't apply.

If you had a bunch of builders which had no I/O and were pure python, then it may have some impact.

Generally speaking you will see a near linear speed up in the time building the software (there is some time spent processing the SConscripts and building the dependency tree which is currently not affected by -j) until such time as you saturate the I/O of the filesystems you are running on and/or have a -j # which significantly exceeds the number of cores you have available.

We may have some benchmarks in the mailing list.

Note that -j specifically won't have any effect on null (incremental builds where nothing needs to be built as all files are up to date) and less effect on incremental builds where only a few files need to build (due to issues noted above).

Comment: So specifying `-j 4` is generally a good idea to be a default for C/C++ builds, right? Some up to date benchmarks with graphs would be nice, indeed.

Comment: Feel free to generate them for your own example and publish! I'm 100% sure any previous benchmarking would have been done by the user community and published on the mailing list.

Comment: Yes, but benchmarks need to be done in certain way. I can't just do benchmarking.

Comment: Feel free.  Capture the output of /usr/bin/time -p for running -j1 .. -j n for a clean build, and for a null build. That'll provide useful information. Make sure nothing else is running on your system at the time.  It may not be perfect, but it's reasonably good.

Comment: If you are on windows you may get good bang for buck by trying batch compiles. take a look at the man page and search for batch.