# Why does higher configured instance on EC2 take more time to run?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, benchmarking

I have a code that calls a function 10 times. The execution of the function is sequential, therefore only after the function has returned for the first instance it will again get called and repeat the same process for 9 more times. The function is doing matrix multiplications and some other stuff which I need to time with respect to increasing EC2 configurations on AWS.

What I have observed with increasing the EC2 configuration, there is a slight increase in execution time (around 7-10 seconds). However the weird thing is there is a jump of 45 seconds when I change the instance type from **1 CPU 1 GB RAM** to **multi-CPU higher RAM**. After this, the jump as mentioned above is not more than 7-10 seconds.

Could anyone please explain to me why am I facing this phenomena? Why the increase in runtime from single CPU to multi CPU?

Here is a sample code for my process :

```
import sys
import datetime

then = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in range(0, 10):
    foo = some_function(arg1, arg2)
    print("*")
now = datetime.datetime.now() - then

print("runtime : ", now)
```

**Here are the actual runtimes :**

1. 1-CPU 1-GB RAM : **00:02:57**
2. 2-CPU 16-GB RAM : **00:03:43**
3. 4-CPU 32-GB RAM : **00:03:47**

So, there is quite a jump in runtime from **(1)** to **(2)** and a marginal jump from **(2)** to **(3)** and so on. Any help in explaining this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe the new instance type is ebs-optimized or has better networking performance?

Comment: The first one is **t3.micro** whereas the next two are **r5.large** and **r5.xlarge**

Comment: r5.large and r5.xlarge are database-optimised instances.  You're comparing apples and cylons

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the details of your program, or the details of the operating system you are running, there are a couple of things that it could be.

1. different operating system tuning settings on the larger instances
2. different underlying physical infrastructure
3. different versions of whatever python (?) runtime you're using - or perhaps the runtime is not compiled with multicore optimizations
4. different versions of glibc or libc on your OS

network times, filesystem speeds etc etc could all be playing in.

short answer: it's difficult to give an answer.

Comment: Under all cases, the underlying OS architecture is the same (Ubuntu) with the exact same configurations. All code executions are done on python 3 and I am just calculating the time at 2 different instances and subtracting the time to get an estimate of running time. Under any scenario as far as I know, this method of runtime estimation will be quite accurate regardless of whatever optimizations. The filesystem is also the same and I don't see how network times can affect the run time.

Comment: You mention above you're using r5 class instances for testing.  Don't.  Use C-class (compute optimized) or M-class (general purpose) instances if you're doing computation.  I would recommend you read up on the different instance types: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

Comment: Thanks! To be honest, I'm new to all this and I really don't know the different AWS architectures. All I am doing is running some code and reporting the timing(s) and I was informed the code is wrong because the timing is unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause is that the underlying libraries you are using take advantage of the multiple CPUs

Single CPU is often more efficient compared with 2 CPU.  You can research how this might affect your particular algorithms - which you don't discuss in the question

See this answer on SO for an example of this phenomenon

[Why does this Python script run 4x slower on multiple cores than on a single core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31386382/why-does-this-python-script-run-4x-slower-on-multiple-cores-than-on-a-single-cor)

Comment: The reason I can't share my approach, algorithms or code is that it belongs to the organization I work for and due to various NDAs I have signed, I am not at a liberty to disclose them. The code sample in the question is the closest I can come to giving a picture about my problems

Comment: yes, and I think that's fine but the answer has to be necessarily general because it's a generalised question as the details cannot be included.  Hope the answer about is useful!